# Duplicate entry for 'IFU67072-I-TEC1' key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am working a web application.
I am facing Below mentioned error.

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Duplicate entry
>   'IFU67072-I-TEC1' for key 'PRIMARY'

when i designed a database that time i used a field datatype varchar .
can anybody help me why its happend?

Comment: Did you know that *Primary Key* must be unique for each rows?

Comment: yes sir I know primary key

Comment: The error above shown because you try to insert UnUnique values to your table.